# Why can't I copy-and-paste from my VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc, copy-paste

I'm running Windows 7 on my host machine using Microsoft Virtual PC; copy-and-paste was working previously but now is not.  Is there are shortcut or quick setting I may have flipped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make sure you install the [Virtual Machine Additions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824561). As well as speeding up the virtual machine, it should enable you to perform `Copy and Paste` as well as a few other features.

If you already have it installed, go to `Settings` > `Integration Features`, and make sure that `Clipboard` is ticked.